# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygimli' in Jupyter - cannot import pyGIMLi

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, modulenotfounderror

I'm trying to use a script (not mine) in Jupyter, using pyGIMLi in it.

I installed pyGIMLi according to the instructions here: https://www.pygimli.org/installation.html. I used the first set of instructions, using conda. So I now have the pyGIMLi saved as an environment in my Anaconda Navigator.

I opened the script I am going to use in Jupyter Notebook and tried to run it, but the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygimli'" was displayed instead.

I do not have a lot of experience with programming, so kindly keep this in mind when answering. I tried restarting the computer, but this did not change anything.

What might be the problem here?

Comment: there are two sets of instructions on that link. are you using `conda` or `pip` ?

Comment: also, i would usually do this:  `python -m pip install -q condacolab` ...

Comment: Alternative to Robin Thibaut's excellent advice, you can also try in the running Jupyter notebook, making a new cell & then running `%conda install -c conda-forge pygimli`. Let that installation finish and restart the kernel after that, and then finally try the import. The magic install commands insure the installations occur in the correct environment where the kernel underlying the notebook is running. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) for more about the magic install commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the Jupyter Notebook might be running in a different environment than the one where you installed `pygimli`.

Here's a step-to-step guide to run your Jupyter Notebook in the correct conda environment:

1. Activate the `pygimli` environment in your terminal.
   If the environment was named `pg`, the command would be `conda activate pg`.
2. After activating the environment, start the Jupyter Notebook from the same terminal by running `jupyter notebook`.
   This should open a new Jupyter Notebook in your default web browser.
3. From here, open the notebook you want to work with.

Your Jupyter notebook should now be able to access the `pygimli` module because it is running in the same environment where the module was installed.

Remember, every time you want to use the module, you should activate the `pg` environment first then start Jupyter Notebook from there.

If the problem persists, it's possible that the `pygimli` module was not installed correctly. Try reinstalling it in your conda environment, and ensure the installation process completed without errors.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved my problem! I really appreciate your well-structured explanation. :)